# Pandas Split Scientific Notation into two Columns - Significand and Exponent

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, formatting

I have a column in a data frame called MARKET_VALUE that I need to pass to a downstream system in a defined format. MARKET_VALUE, a float, needs to be passed as two integer columns (significand, with no trailing zeros and exp) as follows

```
MARKET VALUE   SIGNIFICAND    EXP
6.898806e+09       6898806     3
6.898806e+05       6898806    -1
6.898806e+03       6898806    -3
```

I contemplated using formatted strings but am convinced there must be a smarter solution. The data frame is large, containing millions of rows, so a solution that doesn't depend on apply would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Generate a random pandas dataframe

I use a DataFrame consiting in 1e5 rows (you could try with more to test the bottleneck)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100000,2))**10, columns=['random1', 'random2'])
```

### Use .apply method

In this case I use the standard python formatting.

- *8E* is the number of digits after point.
- *[:-4]* to remove the exponential notation and keep only the significand.
- *[-3:]* to get only the exponential with the sign, then convert it into a **int** value.

```
# get the signficand
df.random1.apply(lambda x: f'{x:.8E}'[:-4].replace('.', ''))
    
# get the exp
df.random1.apply(lambda x: int(f'{x:.0E}'[-3:]))
```

On my laptop it took less than 100ms.

I am thinking about faster solution (vectorized one), but for now I hope that this can help.

Comment: Thanks for that. I believe your exponent calculation needs to have 8 subtracted to get to the correct number but aside from that its a good answer and, as you say reasonably fast